# LDAPException(resultCode=91 (connect error), errorMessage='An error occurred while attempting to connect to server

Tags: java, android, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

I am tring to make an android app to connect at an LDAP server. I am using UnboundId library so my app to be able to establish an LDAP connection. The problem is the resultCode 91-connection error and I don't know how to resolve it. The LDAP server is up and running because my desktop app can establish a connection.
 I will attach the code:

```
           TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
     try {
        LDAPConnection c = new LDAPConnection("192.168.106.131",389,"cn=admin,dc=test,dc=com","haha");

        if(c.isConnected())
        {
            tv.setText("good");
        }
        else
        {
            tv.setText("bad");
        }
    } catch (LDAPException e) {
        tv.setText("error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And the log from LogCat:

```
            05-25 22:56:49.653: E/SELinux(21849): selinux_android_seapp_context_reload:       seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
            05-25 22:56:49.663: D/dalvikvm(21849): Late-enabling CheckJNI
            05-25 22:56:50.184: W/dalvikvm(21849): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/security/sasl/SaslClient;)
            05-25 22:56:50.184: W/dalvikvm(21849): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Ljavax/security/sasl/SaslClient;)
            05-25 22:56:50.194: I/dalvikvm(21849): Could not find method javax.security.sasl.SaslClient.dispose, referenced from method com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnectionInternals.close
            05-25 22:56:50.194: W/dalvikvm(21849): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 12795: Ljavax/security/sasl/SaslClient;.dispose ()V
            05-25 22:56:50.194: D/dalvikvm(21849): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0040
            05-25 22:56:50.214: I/dalvikvm(21849): Could not find method javax.security.sasl.SaslClient.wrap, referenced from method com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnectionInternals.sendMessage
            05-25 22:56:50.214: W/dalvikvm(21849): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 12801: Ljavax/security/sasl/SaslClient;.wrap ([BII)[B
            05-25 22:56:50.214: D/dalvikvm(21849): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x005c
            05-25 22:57:50.448: W/System.err(21849): LDAPException(resultCode=91 (connect error), errorMessage='An error occurred while attempting to connect to server             192.168.106.131:389:  java.io.IOException: Unable to establish a connection to server 192.168.106.131:389 within the configured timeout of 60000 milliseconds.')
            05-25 22:57:50.448: W/System.err(21849):    at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection.connect(LDAPConnection.java:755)
            05-25 22:57:50.448: W/System.err(21849):    at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection.connect(LDAPConnection.java:687)
            05-25 22:57:50.448: W/System.err(21849):    at com.example.aaa.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
            05-25 22:57:50.448: W/System.err(21849):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5255)
            05-25 22:57:50.448: W/System.err(21849):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
            05-25 22:57:50.448: W/System.err(21849):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2213)
            05-25 22:57:50.448: W/System.err(21849):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
            05-25 22:57:50.448: W/System.err(21849):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154)
            05-25 22:57:50.448: W/System.err(21849):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
            05-25 22:57:50.448: W/System.err(21849):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            05-25 22:57:50.458: W/System.err(21849):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            05-25 22:57:50.458: W/System.err(21849):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
            05-25 22:57:50.458: W/System.err(21849):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            05-25 22:57:50.458: W/System.err(21849):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            05-25 22:57:50.458: W/System.err(21849):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            05-25 22:57:50.458: W/System.err(21849):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            05-25 22:57:50.458: W/System.err(21849):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
            05-25 22:57:50.458: W/System.err(21849): Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish a connection to server 192.168.106.131:389 within the configured timeout of 60000 milliseconds.
            05-25 22:57:50.458: W/System.err(21849):    at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnectionInternals.<init>(LDAPConnectionInternals.java:143)
            05-25 22:57:50.458: W/System.err(21849):    at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection.connect(LDAPConnection.java:745)
            05-25 22:57:50.458: W/System.err(21849):    ... 16 more
            05-25 22:57:50.468: W/System.err(21849): LDAPException(resultCode=81 (server down), errorMessage='The connection is not established.')
            05-25 22:57:50.468: W/System.err(21849):    at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection.registerResponseAcceptor(LDAPConnection.java:4228)
            05-25 22:57:50.468: W/System.err(21849):    at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.SimpleBindRequest.process(SimpleBindRequest.java:538)
            05-25 22:57:50.468: W/System.err(21849):    at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection.bind(LDAPConnection.java:1893)
            05-25 22:57:50.468: W/System.err(21849):    at com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection.bind(LDAPConnection.java:1855)
            05-25 22:57:50.468: W/System.err(21849):    at com.example.aaa.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:46)
            05-25 22:57:50.468: W/System.err(21849):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5255)
            05-25 22:57:50.468: W/System.err(21849):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
            05-25 22:57:50.468: W/System.err(21849):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2213)
            05-25 22:57:50.468: W/System.err(21849):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
            05-25 22:57:50.468: W/System.err(21849):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154)
            05-25 22:57:50.468: W/System.err(21849):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
            05-25 22:57:50.468: W/System.err(21849):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            05-25 22:57:50.478: W/System.err(21849):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            05-25 22:57:50.478: W/System.err(21849):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
            05-25 22:57:50.478: W/System.err(21849):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            05-25 22:57:50.478: W/System.err(21849):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            05-25 22:57:50.478: W/System.err(21849):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
            05-25 22:57:50.478: W/System.err(21849):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
            05-25 22:57:50.478: W/System.err(21849):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
            05-25 22:57:50.548: D/libEGL(21849): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
            05-25 22:57:50.548: D/libEGL(21849): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
             05-25 22:57:50.558: D/libEGL(21849): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
            05-25 22:57:50.568: I/Adreno200-EGL(21849): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:265>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:   AYELDER_AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_2.5.5.04.02.02.092.023+PATCH[ES]_msm8960_JB_2.5.5_CL3556704_rel ease_ENGG (CL3556704)
            05-25 22:57:50.568: I/Adreno200-EGL(21849): Build Date: 05/17/13 Fri
            05-25 22:57:50.568: I/Adreno200-EGL(21849): Local Branch: 
            05-25 22:57:50.568: I/Adreno200-EGL(21849): Remote Branch: quic/jb_2.5.5
            05-25 22:57:50.568: I/Adreno200-EGL(21849): Local Patches: 34c9e193f12610d3e68dabd6198d2c4bfbc66974 RB: Update the master timestamp of the hw_image in rb_texture_update_aliased
             05-25 22:57:50.568: I/Adreno200-EGL(21849): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_JB_2.5.5.04.02.02.092.023 + 01d3c78 + e6f0547 +  LOCAL_PATCH[ES]
```

05-25 22:57:50.618: D/OpenGLRenderer(21849): Enabling debug mode 0

Comment: The log says that it is unable to connect to your LDAP server on 389, which is the non-SSL/TLS port.  Are you sure that your server is listening on this port?  As a simple test you can try "telnet 192.168.106.131 389" or try an LDAP Browser - If you search you will find some free ones you can download and use to test

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that the device can't establish a connection to the specified IP address.  192.168.*.* is a private LAN network, so if you're using your carrier's mobile network then it wouldn't have access to it.  If the device is on WiFi, then it's possible that you still might need to have some VPN tunnel.

If you know of a web server running on that same network, then you could use a web browser to test connectivity to that network.  Alternately, you could try the LDAP client with a public directory server (for example, you could try directory.verisign.com on port 389 for unencrypted communication).

Answer (score 0):

I also received this error when debugging some code that was trying to do LDAP operations without calling Connect() first.